# Getting consecutive 5 leave from DB

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have a table like

```
staff_id    |   att_date     |  status

    1          2014-09-04       A
    1          2014-09-05       P
    1          2014-09-07       A
    1          2014-09-08       A
    1          2014-09-10       A
    1          2014-09-11       A
    1          2014-09-12       A          
    2          2014-09-04       P
    3          2014-09-05       P
    4          2014-09-06       P
    2          2014-09-07       A
    3          2014-09-08       P
```

I want to get staff who took continues 5 leaves. for example staff 1 took continues 5 leaves. I have tried this query. But it will list even if a staff took 5 leaves irrespective of continues leave

```
SELECT staff_id,count(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE status = 'A'
GROUP BY staff_id HAVING count(*)>4
```

Comment: Do you have a primary key on that table?

Comment: Yes I have primary key on that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rank query with user defined variables to assign a same rank for each repeated status per staff_id group and in outer query just check the count

```
select staff_id,status,row_num
from (
select *,
@r:= case when @g = staff_id 
     then 
         case when @s <> `status` then @r + 1 else @r end 
      else @r + 1
       end row_num,
@g:= staff_id,
@s:= status
from my_table m
cross join(select @g:=null,@r:=0,@s:=null) t
order by staff_id,att_date,status
) t1
where status = 'A'
group by staff_id
having count(*) >= 5
```

[**`Demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/494b4b/16)

[**`Another demo with changed data`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1d6ba/3)

**Edit for consecutive days**

```
select staff_id,status,row_num
from (
select *,
@r:= case when @g = staff_id 
     then 
         case when @s <> `status` then @r + 1 else @r end 
      else @r + 1
       end row_num,
@g:= staff_id,
@s:= status
from my_table m
cross join(select @g:=null,@r:=0,@s:=null) t
where 
  case when @d is null then 1 else
  DATEDIFF(att_date,  @d) = 1
  end
order by staff_id,att_date,status
) t1
where status = 'A'
group by staff_id
having count(*) >= 5
```

[**`Demo for old data set`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/494b4b/18)

[**`Demo for updated data set`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e44c1/6)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not working as expected. change the 3rd status to P and count(*) >= 4. It is not taking the continues date

Comment: @Shafeeq yes this query will look for continuous status A it will not work for continuous dates

Comment: @Shafeeq also in my answer condition is `>=5` not 4 [`See demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/231937/1)

Comment: @Shafeeq yes because you asked for *It is not taking the continues date* so this query is looking for consecutive dates ,Reason record no.4 and 5 have difference of 2 days missing date 9 in previous data set these was a continuity that why you have results for previous data and in new data dates are not continuous

Comment: Mostly weekend days will be off for the company, so there will be not entry for weekend days and holidays. Now the query works

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable to count consecutive days

```
SELECT staffid ,status FROM
(SELECT staffid,status,
    CASE WHEN att_date=@last_ci+INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN @n ELSE @n:=@n+1 END AS g,
    @last_ci := att_date As att_date
  FROM
    t, (SELECT @n:=0) r
ORDER BY staffid,att_date)x
GROUP BY
staffid,g
HAVING SUM(status='A')>4
AND COUNT(DISTINCT g)=1
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/133ae/2)

Comment: Im little bit confused about att_date field ?? Can you update your answer

Comment: its not working as expected. I have updated my question